# ant task to generate mutiple targets in different project

Tags: ant, junit

i have ant target which invokes simultaneously other 3 projects ant build target for junit. this build target executes all three projects even though any one of the project build fails. Problem here is, if any one of the build fails error message should display after compiling three projects build target but it is not happening, how can i solve it?

```
<target name="mainbuild">
 <antcall target="junit-1">//in different project
 <antcall target="junit-2">//in different project
 <antcall target="junit-3">//in different project
<junitreport todir="./reports">
  <fileset dir="./project-1/reports">
    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="./project-2/reports">
    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="./project-3/reports">
    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <report format="frames" todir="./report/html"/>
</junitreport>
</target>

<target name="junit-1">
.... do somethig 
</target>
<target name="junit-2">
.... do somethig 
</target>
<target name="junit-3">
.... do somethig 
</target>
```

1) main build invokes 3 project,even though build fail in any one of the sub project, build successful message displays at the end, it shouldn't happen

2) if any one the sub project build fails, build report should generate, so that developer can analyze further on his failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have clarified that your targets are in different projects, i.e. different build files, you will have to use the `ant` or `subant` tasks instead of `antcall`. The `subant` task has a parameter called `failonerror` which you can set to false so that a failure will not stop the top-level build. I don't know if it is possible to pass back to the top-level build the information that a sub-project build has actually failed its tests.

If your targets were all in the same project you could change your junit tasks so that they don't fail if a test fails, but instead set a property to indicate that a failure has occurred:

```
<junit failureProperty="test.failed"> ... </junit>
```

Then you can make your mainbuild target fail after generating the JUnit report:

```
<fail if="test.failed"> ... </fail>
```

I learned this from the book "Ant in Action".